# Can this contract be killed?

Tags: solidity, mining, contract-design

Would you be willing to share your expert knowledge and your opinion? Please note the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Eternal {

    string engravedText;

    function Eternal(string eT) payable {
        engravedText = eT;
    }

    function getEngravedText() constant returns (string) {
        return engravedText;
    }

}
```

Once it has been mined, it is meant to reside in the blockchain unchanged and forever. Its sole purpose is to provide its engraved text. Ako engravement in a granite brick that may be dug up in centuries from now.

Is that the case? Can it be killed by an outside force? If not, is it likely that any removal mechanisms will be created in the future that shortens its expected lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look as though there are any blaring issues. This should be able to persist untouched. I'm also doubtful that any mechanism will be created that will shorten the lifespan of the above contract.

And that'll be 20 ETH for the contract audit *sarcasm*

Comment: I should note the constructor is payable, and it will acept payments in ether, but the contract doesn't provide any method to spend them.

Comment: The "payable" has no intentional purpose. My question is about the lifetime of  a deployed contract in general. @flygoing thx for your quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Contracts can never be killed unless there is a function explicitly saying to do so.